# Preserving Data Locality in Accumulo

Tags: accumulo

Recently I've been watching the data locality on my Accumulo cluster and I've noticed that it seems to be deteriorating over time. My instinct tells me that it's due to the master redistributing the tablets to help balance out the cluster, specifically after I've completed a rolling restart.

I'm thinking of setting up manual major compactions to run overnight against all of my tables to keep this data locality as close to 100% as possible. Is this something any of you have done before or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you continue to write more data into Accumulo, you'll have a "not-quite-100%" locality measurement. As you write more data, you'll cause tablets to split: one tablet becomes two. Typically, after a split, one of the children will be moved to another server because it invalidates the distribution of tablets which Accumulo is trying to maintain. Until the child tablet of a split itself gets automatically major compacted, you won't have any locality. This is actually an area where Accumulo could make more intelligent decisions about balancing tablets, favoring HDFS locality instead of just the distribution of tablets across tabletservers (but that would be a major effort to undertake).

For your case, it's certainly not absurd to consider running a major compaction on cron overnight (or whenever your "off-peak" time is). We could probably even do something smart and create a tool which judges the locality of all tablets for a table and actually prune down the number of tablets that are below some threshold of locality (e.g. <90% local) which would help avoid re-compacting data which is already local.

If you're interested, please feel free to subscribe and send a message to user@accumulo.apache.org; I would be happy to help out in more detail there.